# Headphone ANC wired support?

Tags: headphones

I'm looking wired noise cancelling headphones. I do not want bluetooth models as they are hindered by their latency. I however found none. If there are no wired headphones that support ANC, why is that?

Comment: There are noise-canceling headphones which have a wired connection in addition to bluetooth, and the noise-canceling part can be active while using the cable input, or no input at all. If you exclude all bluetooth models, you'll miss all of these headphones as well.